# Efficiently matching IP addresses with a list of CIDRs

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, ip-address

I am using Python3 to extract some information from a dictionary that contains 10k of CIDRs, but the running time is pretty long.

Here is my purpose: I have a dictionary of CIDRs (10000) and a list of IPs (5000), then I want to go through each IP in the list and check if it belongs to one CIDR in the dictionary.

Could you please give me some trick to reduce the running time?

```
#python 3:
import os
import ipaddress

Dict = {127.0.0.0/8 : ABC, 169.128.0.0/16 : DEF}
List = {127.0.0.1, 126.1.1.1, 169.2.2.2, 150.0.22.2}

for IP in List:
  for CIDR in Dict.keys():
    if ipaddress.ip_address(IP) in ipaddress.ip_network(CIDR):
      print(CIDR)
      break
```

Comment: you break if you find the first CIDR for an IP. Is this because your CIDR definitions have no IP adress in common? They are pairwise mutually exclusive? If this is the case you can use some sorted auxiliary list that contains the first address of each CIDR and the CIDR. The possible candidate can be found by a binary search.

Comment: The CIDR can contain the lowest address so you have only to store the CIDR and use an appropriate comparison operator

Comment: maybe compare_networks works

Comment: Thanks @miracle173 for comments.
Yes, the list of CIDRS is pairwise exclusive, therefore each IP can just belong at most one CIDR.

Comment: Could you please update your code so that it is syntactically correct?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, welcome to Code Review! This is a great first question. There are some things to learn about how to post a question in order to get the best response, so I'll cover these first and then cover the performance problems that you're seeing.

## Readability

You will get more reviews if your code is readable. I find the layout of your code very clear and readable apart from two things.

1. Your indenting uses only 2 spaces instead of the [recommended 4](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
2. Your variable names `Dict` and `List` are not descriptive and start with an uppercase letter (which is generally reserved for classes)

I understand that these two variables are not part of the code you use in the real world setting and were just quickly added for the purposes of this question. However, it's worth using clear variable names and standard indenting because the reviewer won't have your familiarity with the code.

Note that your `List` is not a list, since you have used braces `{` and `}` instead of square brackets `[` and `]`. Braces denote a set, or a dict if key value pairs are used. In your case `List` is a set, which has different behaviour.

## Running your code before you post it

You didn't run this code before you posted it, and it contains syntax errors as pointed out by [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success).
You can't be expected to spot every minor typo in your code before you post it. However, you are expected to **run the code** before you post it. This would have picked up the problem with `Dict` and with `List`. It only takes a moment and means you will get more meaningful reviews, less confusion, and use up less of the reviewers time so they can help more people.

Since the site rules require working code, it would be perfectly reasonable for a reviewer to simply move on to the next question if this one has code that doesn't run. For this reason you are also likely to get more reviews and to see your first review sooner if you run your code before posting it.

For reference, the syntax errors on both lines are due to not enclosing strings in quotes, so that python tries to evaluate them as expressions.

```
Dict = {127.0.0.0/8 : ABC, 169.128.0.0/16 : DEF}
List = {127.0.0.1, 126.1.1.1, 169.2.2.2, 150.0.22.2}
```

should be:

```
Dict = {'127.0.0.0/8' : 'ABC', '169.128.0.0/16' : 'DEF'}
List = {'127.0.0.1', '126.1.1.1', '169.2.2.2', '150.0.22.2'}
```

## Repeating work

You are repeating two things, each of which slows down your program.

1. You convert `IP` using `ipaddress.ip_address(IP)`. This conversion always gives the same output for a given `IP`, so you can calculate it once at the start of the outer loop rather than recalculating the same thing every time you start the inner loop.
2. You convert `CIDR` using `ipaddress.ip_network(CIDR)`. Each time through the inner loop you will be converting the same list of `CIDR`s. If you have sufficient memory you can calculate all of these once, and then use those precalculated values rather than recalculating.

You state that there are 10,000 `CIDR`s and 5,000 `IP`s.

The first problem will therefore repeat the `IP` conversion on average 5,000 times for cases where a match is found (because on average it will get half way through the 10,000 `CIDR`s before finding the match). Where no match is found it will repeat the `IP` conversion 10,000 times, once for each `CIDR`. Between 5,000 and 10,000 conversions for each of 5,000 `IP`s is **between 25,000,000 and 50,000,000 conversions when only 5,000 are needed** (once per `IP`).

The second problem will repeat all 10,000 `CIDR` conversions for any `IP` that does not find a match, and on average 5,000 `CIDR` conversions for any `IP` that does find a match. That's **between 25,000,000 and 50,000,000 conversions when only 10,000 are needed** (once per `CIDR`).

## How to return an unconverted `CIDR`

I can see why you might be tempted to loop over unconverted `CIDR`s - you return an unconverted `CIDR` so working with a list of converted `CIDR`s would mean you'd have to find out which `CIDR` the converted `CIDR` came from before returning it.

You can return the unconverted CIDR by creating a dict at the start which has converted `CIDR` as the key and original `CIDR` as the value.

For example:

```
converted_CIDRs = {ipaddress.ip_network(CIDR):CIDR for CIDR in Dict.keys()}
```

Now you can work with converted CIDRs to avoid all that recalculation, and still return an unconverted CIDR at the end by doing a quick dictionary lookup using the converted CIDR as the key.

Answer (score 3):

I'll point out that IPv4Networks can return their first address, using an index of `[0]`.

I'll further point out that an IPv4Address can be converted to an integer using `int(addr)`.

Thus, you can sort your CIDRs according to the first address in their range, and you can sort your IP addresses according to themselves. The two orders will be comparable.

This means you can essentially "merge" your two lists by sorting them in order, then iterating over the two of them in parallel.

This will be essentially O(n log n) + O(m log m) + O(n+m) time, where n = number of addresses, m = number of networks.